# Cordova 3.5.0 return 0 sometimes ,for navigator.connection.type

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-notifications, cordova-plugins

i am trying to develop a cordova(**3.5.0**) project in android platform and in that i have to check network connection availability before each API call. for that i am using '**navigator.connection.type**',and some times it return 0. why this is happening?  plz help me for solving this trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some more details I can only guess.. There are some conditions which may cause this.

`navigator.connection.type = 0` -> connection type unknown.

So you may have a connection, you may not it simply hasn't been determined yet, or because of privileges the device isn't saying.

Are you calling this check too early? ie before deviceready

In our app we do not check the connection each time but we handle it this way:

by making the API request anyway, knowing that its possible to fail, we set a timeout and error handling. If it fails by error or timeout we check connection type and then ping the server with a simple "hello" "acknowledge" request. Its a super small request that we figure will work or if it timeouts again the connection must be so poor it might as well be disconnected.

This is because there are really two types of connection you need to check. Many miss this!

And also because its navigator totally lies some times... :/

Just because wifi is on and connected and navigator tells you this, it doesn't mean you will have a connection to the outside world. You need to check the network hardware (which is all navigator will tell you) but you must also check network connectivity, if this is something you are sensitive about.